# Button that moves its own container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button inside of a div that I would like to slide when the button is clicked.  The div slides when the button is outside of the sliding div, but when I move the button inside of the div it stops sliding.

I understand why it is happening, but just don't how to make it work.

Here is the working Html with the button outside.

```
<div class="slide">
    <button type="button" id="slideleft" class="btn btn-default alert_button " title="New Message!" style="border: none; background-color: none !important;"></button>
    <div class="inner" style="margin-right: -100px;"></div>           
</div>
```

Here is the Html that I would like to work, with the button inside.

```
<div class="slide">
    <div class="inner" style="margin-right: -100px;">
        <button type="button" id="slideleft" class="btn btn-default alert_button " title="New Message!" style="border: none; background-color: none !important;"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery controlling the sliding action.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slideleft').click(function(slide) {
        var $lefty = $(this).next();
        $lefty.animate({
            left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
                -$lefty.outerWidth() : 
                0
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Try changing `var $lefty = $(this).next();` with `var $lefty = $(this).parent();`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want but when the button is not within `.inner` your code `var $lefty = $(this).next();` targets the .inner div. If you want to put the button within the div you need `var $lefty = $(this).parent();`